# VBA property Let - two arguments

Tags: excel, vba, parameters

So I have two different classes, the main and the object class. The thing is that I want to send two arrays to `setArray` but `Property Let` doesn't allow me too. How can I do this, I know that `dData.setArray = xData(0), xData(1)`  is wrong but that's how I would do it if I have one argument.

Main:

```
dData.setArray = xData(0), xData(1)
```

Object Class:

```
Property Let setArray(name As Variant, value As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(name)
        data.Add CStr(name(i)), CInt(value(i))
    Next i
End Property
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a Method instead of a property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* have property lets with multiple arguments, but obviously with only one 'right hand side', which is the last argument in the property signature (`value As Variant` in your case). The assignment syntax for your signature will be this:

```
dData.setArray(xData(0)) = xData(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pass the arrays as one jagged array, you may achieve this with the following code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myObject As New someObject
    Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array("a", "b")
    myObject.Members = Array(arr1, arr2)

    Dim arrCnt As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    'This is how to access the values in the jagged array:
    For arrCnt = LBound(myObject.Members) To UBound(myObject.Members)
        For counter = LBound(myObject.Members(arrCnt)) To UBound(myObject.Members(arrCnt))
            Debug.Print myObject.Members(arrCnt)(counter)
        Next counter
    Next arrCnt

End Sub
```

The class looks like this:

```
Private m_Members As Variant

Public Property Get Members() As Variant
    Members = m_Members
End Property

Public Property Let Members(ByVal NewValue As Variant)
    m_Members = NewValue
End Property
```